# Converting Python Nested Lists To JSON

Tags: python, json

I want to convert a list of lists (of lists, etc) in Python into JSON. It seems like I need to either convert to a dictionary first, or iterate manually to make pseudo-JSON.

The goal is to somehow be able to input such a list of lists and return nicely formatted JSON.

List form:

```
['Templates', [[['Name', 'Apple Pie'], ['Manufacturer', 'Burger King'], ['Model', 'Apple'], ['Type', 'Pie'], ['Info', [[['Pack Size', 3], ['Cost', 12]], [['Pack Size', 1], ['Cost', 5]]]]], [['Name', 'Vanilla Icecream'], ['Manufacturer', 'JP Licks'], ['Model', 'Vanilla'], ['Type', 'Icecream'], ['Info', [[['Pack Size', 2], ['Cost', 12]], [['Pack Size', 3], ['Cost', 14]]]]], [['Name', 'Raspberry Cream Cheese'], ['Manufacturer', 'Philadelphia'], ['Model', 'Raspberry'], ['Type', 'Cream cheese'], ['Info', [[['Pack Size', 4], ['Cost', 9]], [['Pack Size', 2], ['Cost', 6]]]]]]]
```

Converted in JSON to:

```
{
"Templates" : [
    {
        "Name" : "Apple Pie",
        "Manufacturer" : "Burger King",
        "Model" : "Apple",
        "Type" : "Pie",
        "Info" : [
            {
                "Pack Size" : 3,
        "Cost" : 12

            },
            {
                "Pack Size" : 1,
        "Cost" : 5
            }
        ]
    },

    {
        "Name" : "Vanilla Icecream",
        "Manufacturer" : "JP Licks",
        "Model" : "Vanilla",
        "Type" : "Icecream",
        "Info" : [
            {
                "Pack Size" : 2,
        "Cost" : 12
            },
            {
                 "Pack Size" : 3,
         "Cost" : 14
            }
        ]
    },

    {
        "Name" : "Raspberry Cream Cheese",
        "Manufacturer" : "Philadelphia",
        "Model" : "Raspberry",
        "Type" : "Cream cheese",
        "Info" : [
            {
                 "Pack Size" : 4,
         "Cost" : 9
            },
            {
                 "Pack Size" : 2,
         "Cost" : 6
            }

        ]
    }
],
```

}

Comment: How is it supposed to know when to convert to a dictionary and when to not? `['Manufacturer', 'Burger King']` could have also been left as a list.

Comment: Please show your attempt. After converting the data structure, `json.dumps` may be helpful. To check the type of a variable, use `isinstance`

Comment: @Selcuk, if there is only one element, then it's not a dict, if it is, then I go to a dict.

Comment: @Aaron maybe I don't understand (Well I know I don't...), how does the data structure need to be converted?